# Is there any substantial study regarding the automorphism of the field $k((x_1,\cdots, x_n)):=\text{Frac}(k[[x_1, \cdots, x_n]])$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, automorphism-group

Let $k$ be a local field, and consider the local ring of the formal power series $k[[x_1, \cdots, x_n]]$.

Consider the field of fraction $k((x_1,\cdots, x_n)):=\text{Frac}(K[[x_1, \cdots, x_n]])$.

It is not a local field, but we can define a discrete valuation for it.

I am interested in automorphisms of $k((x_1,\cdots, x_n))$.

- Is there any substantial study in this direction?

For example, if $k=\mathbb Q_p$, then $\text{Aut}(k)=\{id\}$ and therefore the automorphisms of $k((x_1,\cdots, x_n))$ will be determined by the permutations of $x_1, \cdots, x_n$ and in this case, the automorphism will be of infinite order, mostly.

When $k=\mathbb F_p((t))$, in this case also $\text{Aut}(k((x_1,\cdots, x_n)))$ will contain elements of inifinite order.

- How does $\text{Aut}(k)$ extend to $\text{Aut}(k((x_1,\cdots, x_n)))$?

I appreciates on any reference or comments.